# Не работает правильно команда test с переменной

Tags: bash

Помогите разобраться с лабой:
команда test, когда он задан через переменную. При чем я вывел значение переменной в файл (1.txt, ниже в коде видно), скопировал имя файла из файла и скормил  test'у непосредственно строкой (чтоб исключить возможную проблему с кодировкой символов в имени файла), и все работает. Я уже не знаю, что подозревать...

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in $files
do
  f="~$f"       # в f изначально имена файлов формата типа /data/xxxx.xxx
  echo "$f">>1.txt #просто контроль, что же я буду передавать команде test...
  if [ -f "$f" ] ; then  # проблема здесь - результат False (((
    echo "$f" >> ~/data/oldFiles.txt
  fi
done
```

Дополнение после ответа форумчанина:

Спасибо за ответ! Если я правильно понял обьяснение, как ОС работает с тильдой, то тогда такая конструкция

```
file='/data/1.txt'
if [ -f "~$file" ]
```

должна работать, ведь здесь тильда явно задается сразу в test? А она тоже выдает False... Для True у меня на компе нужно именно явно задать и тильду, и имя файла...

Comment: Так а что собственно не работает? Вообще смущает что тильда добавляется дважды.

Comment: И что это скрипт *должен* делать?

Comment: Алексей,  тут вопрос не в том, что должен делать скрипт, а чисто синтаксис... Как я написал ниже, выяснилось, что если в переменной есть тильда, то команда test "не находит" файл, а если задавать в явном виде, то без проблем обрабатывает...  Вообще данный фрагмент записывает полное имя файла из списка $files , в файл oldFiles.txt - при условии, что данный файл еще существует в реальности

Comment: Я изменил свой скрипт и использовал не тильду, а двоеточие. Т.е.

"../data/aaa.xyz" а не "~/data/aaa.xyz".

В моем случае оба пути технически верно указывают на один тот же файл, но когда в переменной была тильда, команда внутри if возвращала ложь, а с двоеточием - все ок... Но, когда я задавал в команде путь с тильдой в явном виде, а не через переменную, то тоже все ок.

Короче, почему не пропускает тильду "в переменной", я так и не понял

Comment: У вас тильда находится в кавычках, поэтому это является буквально символом тильда. Чтобы `bash` воспринимал тильду как домашнюю директорию, нужно убрать кавычки. Например, это можно сделать так: написать `TILDA=~; f="$TILDA$f"` вместо `f="~$f"`. Другой вариант, вызвать `echo` следующим образом: `f="$(echo ~)$f"`. Или просто используйте переменную окружения HOME: `f="$HOME$f"` (как вам уже об этом написал [Zt](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1510078) в своем ответе).

Comment: @VadikSirekanyan спасибо!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**первое**

> ```
> f="~$f" # в f изначально имена файлов формата типа /data/xxxx.xxx
> ```

лучше сразу привыкайте к относительным и абсолютным путям:
`относительный/путь` и `/абсолютный/путь`

то есть, если вы в файл *нагрепали* относительных путей то не начинайте их с косой, здесь правильнее будет записывать как `data/xxxx.xxx` а не `/data/xxxx.xxx`. Также это позволит проще разбираться в коде где путь записывается в переменную, у вас это будет выглядеть как `f=~/$f`

**второе**

В **скриптах**,вместо тильды(`~`), по возможности лучше всё же стараться использовать стандартную переменную `$HOME`, как то `f="$HOME/$f"`, что позволит не заморачиваться с запоминанием некоторых нюансов при *раскрытие выражений*.

**третье**

[Раскрытие выражений (expansion)](http://rus-linux.net/kos.php?name=/book1/gl-05/gl_05_07.html)

> Когда оболочка получает какую-то командную строку на выполнение, она
> до начала выполнения команды осуществляет "грамматический разбор"
> полученной командной строки. Одним из этапов такого "разбора" является
> раскрытие или подстановка выражений (expansion). В bash имеется семь
> типов подстановки выражений:
>
> - раскрытие скобок (brace expansion);
> - **замена знака тильды (tilde expansion);**
> - **подстановка параметров и переменных;**
> - подстановка команд;
> - арифметические подстановки (выполняемые слева направо);
> - разделение слов (word splitting);
> - раскрытие шаблонов имен файлов и каталогов (pathname expansion).
>
> Все эти **операции выполняются именно в том порядке, как они здесь**
> **перечислены**. Рассмотрим их последовательно.

повторю, порядок раскрытия важен.

В упрощенном варианте ваша проблема выглядит так:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -o xtrace

touch ~/test.file

f="~/test.file" 
[ -f "$f" ]; echo $?
# test -f "$f"; echo $?

rm -f ~/test.file

exit
```

отладочный вывод через `xtrace`

```
+ touch /home/.../test.file
+ f='~/test.file'
+ '[' -f '~/test.file' ']'
+ echo 1
1
+ rm -f /home/.../test.file
+ exit
```

где видно, что из за того что путь при присвоении переменной `f` закавычен то замена знака тильды(`~`) не произошла, а далее при раскрытии выражения в `test` замена знака тильды также не происходит потому что её попусту еще не видно, а видно её тока после подстановки переменной `f`, но как говорится - "поезд уже ушёл" *(подстановка сначала тильды, а потом переменной, но не наоборот)*

Вот и выходит что `test` смотрит файл по относительному пути `~/test.file` где `~` это не домашняя директория пользователя, а реальное название папки в текущей директории и естественно не находит такой.

**дополнение**

> Если я правильно понял обьяснение, как ОС работает с тильдой...

нет, ОС не работает с тильдой, в данном случае с тильдой *работает* командный интерпретатор BASH.

> такая конструкция
>
> ```
> file='/data/1.txt'
> if [ -f "~$file" ]
> ```
>
> должна работать, ведь здесь тильда явно задается сразу в test? А она
> тоже выдает False... Для True у меня на компе нужно именно явно задать
> и тильду, и имя файла...

вы должны были уже понять что замена тильды в кавычках неработает и всегда интерпритирутся bash как обычный символ `~`; правильно здесь будет тильду вывести за кавычки:

```
[ -f ~"$file" ]
```

но и это еще не всё, чтобы *правильно раскрыть* тильду в слове, должны соблюдаться ряд условий которые описанны в вышеупомянутой мной статье [Раскрытие выражений (expansion)](http://rus-linux.net/kos.php?name=/book1/gl-05/gl_05_07.html) раздела **5.7.2 Замена тильды (Tilde Expansion)**, если кратко то примерно так:

```
echo "~"     # ~
echo ~"/"    # ~/
echo ~"xyz"  # ~xyz

echo ~       # /home/$USER
echo ~/      # /home/$USER/
echo ~/"xyz" # /home/$USER/xyz
```

посему верным будет такая запись:

```
file='data/1.txt'
[ -f ~/"$file" ]
```

но с вашим упорством ставить слешь в начале относительного пути мугу предложить разве что обходной вариант:

```
file='/data/1.txt'
[ -f $(printf "%s%s" ~ "$file") ]
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, это такая лабораторная работа, не  я придумал слеш писать впереди.

Comment: Я попробовал другой способ, основанный на вашем описании работы тильды, посмотрите обновленный текст вопроса. Может, я все равно до конца не понял принцип работы ОС с тильдой...